# SetWindowPos doesn't work with VSCode windows

Tags: visual-studio-code, winapi, electron, user32, setwindowpos

I'm trying to move the VSCode window using `SetWindowPos` (in PowerShell, however the same should apply to C++ or C# PInvoke) and I cannot get it to work.

Even more frustratingly NirSoft's GUIPropView utility *does* manage to move (using the Center Selected Windows option) the VSCode window somehow. (And *of course* there's no source code available for that program...)

I'm able to get some kind of handle using the following PowerShell code:

```
$hwnd = (Get-Process code).MainWindowHandle | where { $_ -ne 0 }
```

This yields the handle as when using `FindWindow` (supplying the window class and title of the VSCode instance).

Using this handle for `SetWindowPos` does absolutely nothing apart from making `SetWindowPos` return `True` (meaning it at least didn't fail *completely*, I suppose?).

```
$user32 = Add-Type -MemberDefinition @'
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, UInt32 uFlags);
'@ -Name user32 -PassThru

# just some test coordinates and sizes
$user32::SetWindowPos($hwnd, 0, 100, 100, 500, 500, 0)
```

GUIPropView also gave me two other handles (shown in a bottom panel in the program), of which I have no idea where they came from, and one of those allows me to resize and reposition the rendered content, but not the whole window itself, producing a result like this:
[image: weirdness]

**Is there something obvious I'm missing? Should I obtain the window handle differently? What's going on?**

Comment: Visual Studio code is based on Electron which itself is base on Chromium, so the app has   a complex windowing structure, you're probably not getting the good window handle. Otherwise you should UI Automation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) and the TransformPattern (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uiautomationclient/nf-uiautomationclient-iuiautomationtransformpattern-move) to move a window you don't own, it works fine with VS Code. Not sure what's the easiest way to do it in PowerShell though.

Comment: `MainWindowHandle` is made up by the .NET Framework. It suggests the concept of a "main window," which does not exist in the OS. The implementation is based on heuristics (i.e., guessing) and seemingly ran out of luck in the case of Visual Studio Code.

Comment: @SimonMourier Yeah I figured I was targetting the wrong handle already, but that makes me really confused as to how GUIPropView is somehow able to target the right handle. I suppose if I could iterate over *all* window handles and setting their position I'll eventually end up moving the right one, right? Or would that introduce even more issues?
UI Automation looks really complicated, do you happen to know about an example program for moving windows or something in that direction?

Comment: The problem is you take the first code.exe process, while since it's chromimum undecovers, it spawns a lot of these. Here is a simple C# + UIAutomation code that works: https://pastebin.com/raw/RvVHyb8Y

Comment: @SimonMourier Ah I figured it out, apparently VSCode doesn't like to be moved while maximized (I've tested this with other applications such as Firefox and they didn't have any issues with that). Your UIAutomation code retrieves the window handle the exact same way I do in PowerShell - `(Get-Process code).MainWindowHandle | where { $_ -ne 0 }` does the same as `(Get-Process code | where { $_.MainWindowHandle -ne 0 }).MainWindowHandle` or your C# code `Process.GetProcessesByName("code").FirstOrDefault(p => p.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)`.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out the code I had for finding the handle to the VSCode window was actually fine. The issue was trying to move/resize the window while it was still maximized. (Note that other applications I tested this with, such as Firefox, do not have any issues with that.)

To unmaximize/unminimize/unarrange the window, we can use [`ShowWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow) with `SWP_RESTORE`.

The full script is as follows:

```
$user32 = Add-Type -MemberDefinition @'
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, UInt32 uFlags);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
'@ -Name user32 -PassThru

$hwnd = (Get-Process code).MainWindowHandle | Where-Object { $_ -ne 0 }

$user32::ShowWindow($hwnd, 0x0009 <# SW_RESTORE #>);
$user32::SetWindowPos($hwnd, 0, 100, 100, 500, 500, 0);
```